# Type-class instance discoverability - how to search?

Tags: haskell

Example - [Data.List](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html) has an instance defined for [Data.Foldable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.3.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html), but it is defined in Foldable not in List (and against "[]" rather than "List").

For cases where the instance is defined in the same file as the type itself (e.g. [Data.Sequence](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.3.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html)) it's listed in the docs. For the example, I'm not having any luck with Hoogle or Hayoo.

While I can see the most common ocurrence would be the instance definition with the data-type definition, having it in a separate file must happen on occasion. Did I just happen to choose a bad example with Data.List, or am I missing something in my search skills?

---

Clarification: I already know about Foldable and lists and it's reasonable to expect everyone to have come across both fairly early on in exploring Haskell. However, for some complex type T from e.g. Snap/Yesod/lens there's less chance of me knowing that some more complex typeclass I've never come across is relevant. I was wondering if there was some way of explicitly searching for instances in the case that they aren't defined in the type's file (where it can be picked up in the type's auto-generated docs).

Comment: AFAIK `Data.List` implements the `[]` (and its functions) which is part of the `Prelude`, but `Foldable` is **not** part of the `Prelude`. Adding instances of `Foldable` to the `Prelude` would add a non-required dependency on an external package, which ins't a good idea. The `Prelude` should be able to work without any dependency. Hence those instances are put in the file that defines the class.

Comment: @Bakuriu Actually, it's not a dependency on an external package - `Data.Foldable` is in `base`. And GHC 7.10 is moving to export `Foldable` and `Traversable` from `Prelude`, actually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> and against "[]" rather than "List"

well... there is no such type as `List` (at least [not in the standard library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.4.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-List.html#t:ListT))!

Haskell instances can be defined just as well in the class' module as in the data type module (or indeed anywhere else, though such *orphan instances* are rather avoided). The choice depends on which module is more "fundamental": the more quirky module will depend on the more standard one, and an instance can only be defined when both class and type are in scope. As `[]` has always been one of the fundamentals of Haskell, while `Foldable` is more of a particular interface for more advanced generic programming; so it is natural to define the `Foldable []` instance only in the `Foldable` module.

The easiest tool for finding where an instance is defined is GHCi. In your example

> **Prelude>** :m +Data.Foldable
>   **Prelude Data.Foldable>** :i Foldable
>   class Foldable (t :: * -> *) where
>     fold :: Data.Monoid.Monoid m => t m -> m
>     foldMap :: Data.Monoid.Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
>     Data.Foldable.foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
>     foldr' :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
>     Data.Foldable.foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
>     foldl' :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
>     Data.Foldable.foldr1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
>     Data.Foldable.foldl1 :: (a -> a -> a) -> t a -> a
>       -- *Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’*
>   instance **Foldable [] -- *Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’***
>   instance Foldable Maybe -- *Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’*
>   instance Foldable (Either a) -- *Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’*
>   instance Foldable ((,) a) -- *Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’*

It works the other way around as well:

> **Prelude Data.Foldable>** :i []
>   data [] a = [] | a : [a]    -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Types’*
>   instance Eq a => Eq [a] -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’*
>   instance Monad [] -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Base’*
>   instance Functor [] -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Base’*
>   instance Ord a => Ord [a] -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’*
>   instance Read a => Read [a] -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Read’*
>   instance Show a => Show [a] -- *Defined in ‘GHC.Show’*
>   instance **Foldable [] -- *Defined in ‘Data.Foldable’***

Now, of course this won't display any instance that's not even in scope. It *shouldn't*: anybody could define instances for their own obscure type classes in some package that happens to be installed on your system; it wouldn't be helpful to display those. But if you're in a larger framework and use the "standard imports", you'll get all the "standard instances as well, like

> **Prelude Yesod>** :i Html
>   type Html = Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup
>       -- *Defined in ‘Text.Blaze.Html’*
>   **Prelude Yesod>** :i Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup
>   type Text.Blaze.Internal.Markup = Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM ()
>       -- *Defined in ‘Text.Blaze.Internal’*
>   **Prelude Yesod>** :i Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>   type role Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM phantom
>   data Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM a where
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.Parent :: Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> (Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                                                  b) -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                                                          a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.CustomParent :: Text.Blaze.Internal.ChoiceString -> (Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                b) -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                        a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.Leaf :: Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                                               a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.CustomLeaf :: Text.Blaze.Internal.ChoiceString -> Bool -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                     a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.Content :: Text.Blaze.Internal.ChoiceString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                          a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.Append :: (Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                      b) -> (Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                               c) -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.AddAttribute :: Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.StaticString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.ChoiceString -> (Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                                                        a) -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                                                                a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.AddCustomAttribute :: Text.Blaze.Internal.ChoiceString -> Text.Blaze.Internal.ChoiceString -> (Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                          a) -> Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>                                                                                                                                  a
>     Text.Blaze.Internal.Empty :: Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM a
>       -- *Defined in ‘Text.Blaze.Internal’*
>   instance Monad Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>     -- *Defined in ‘Text.Blaze.Internal’*
>   instance Functor Text.Blaze.Internal.MarkupM
>     -- *Defined in ‘Text.Blaze.Internal’*
>   instance ToWidgetHead site Html -- *Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’*
>   instance render ~ Yesod.Core.Types.RY site =>
>            ToWidgetHead site (render -> Html)
>     -- *Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’*
>   instance ToWidgetBody site Html -- *Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’*
>   instance render ~ Yesod.Core.Types.RY site =>
>            ToWidgetBody site (render -> Html)
>     -- *Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’*
>   instance ToWidget site Html -- Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’
>   instance render ~ Yesod.Core.Types.RY site =>
>            ToWidget site (render -> Html)
>     -- *Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Widget’*
>   instance ToTypedContent Html -- Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Content’
>   instance ToFlushBuilder Html -- Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Content’
>   instance ToContent Html -- Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Content’
>   instance HasContentType Html -- Defined in ‘Yesod.Core.Content’
>   instance [overlap ok] PersistField Html
>     -- *Defined in ‘persistent-1.3.3:Database.Persist.Class.PersistField’*

Comment: OK, Thanks. So basically I can rely on the "right thing" working with ghci (once I've installed the library).